# Spring Boot Redis-Template call raw commands like HMGET

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

is Redis-Template having method which support HMGET commands.
which method I can use from Redis-Template to run this command **"HMGET KEY field1 field2"**?

Also How do we run the same command through Redis-Template?, So without going for predefined method, I directly want to run the above/any command through a method , do we have support for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redis-Template there is method called `opsForHash()` for `HASH` data structures, such methods are recommended way of working with Redis commands.

However if you really want yo use "raw" commands you can use `connection.execute()`, here is an example:

```java
@Component
public class RedisDemo {
    private final RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RedisDemo(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }
    
    // This method can execute any command
    public Object executeCommand(String command, byte[]... parts) {
        return redisTemplate.execute(connection ->
             connection.execute(command, parts),
             true
        );
    }
}
```

Calling this method:

```java
redisDemo.executeCommand(
   "HMGET", 
   "test".getBytes(), 
   "field1".getBytes(), 
   "field1".getBytes()
);
```

Just for comparation here is example with `opsForHash()`:

```java
public List<Object> callHMGet() {
    return redisTemplate.opsForHash().multiGet(
        "test", 
        List.of("field1", "field2")
    );
}
```